# Cannot define appropriate rust lifetime requirements

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

TL;DR
Having problems with lifetime with nested objects. Code is below.

Long Version:

I'm writing a multiplayer game using `ggez`, and I'm trying to create an abstraction layer for the input (to allow local and remote players play together).

In order to so, I've created an `Input` trait, and implemented `KeyboardInput` for local input, which uses `ggez` keyboard state querying methods.

Now the tricky part: `ggez` creates `Context` object at startup, and expects a reference to it in most of the functions that is exposes.

because my `KeyboardInput` implementation is using `ggez` input method (specifically, `is_key_pressed`), it has to pass `&Context` to this method. However, since the trait itself should be generic, it won't need a `Context` reference for any other implementation (for example, `NetworkInput`).

my solution was to add a reference to `Context` as field in the `KeyboardInput` struct. However, that caused a lifetime error that I'm still unable to resolve.

I also tried to make the lifetime `'static`, but that did not work either.

here is the relevant code:

```
pub trait Input {
    fn get_direction(&self) -> Direction;
}

pub struct KeyboardInput<'a> {
    left_key: KeyCode,
    right_key: KeyCode,
    _ctx: &'a Context
}

impl KeyboardInput<'_> {
    pub fn new(_ctx: &Context, left_key: KeyCode, right_key: KeyCode) -> KeyboardInput {
        KeyboardInput{
            _ctx,
            left_key,
            right_key
        }
    }
}

impl Input for KeyboardInput<'_> {
    fn get_direction(&self) -> Direction {
        if ggez::input::keyboard::is_key_pressed(self._ctx, self.left_key) {
            return Direction::Left;
        }
        if ggez::input::keyboard::is_key_pressed(self._ctx, self.right_key) {
            return Direction::Right;
        }
        Direction::Unchanged
    }
}

struct Player {
    angle: f32,
    pos_x: f32,
    pos_y: f32,
    input_manager: Box<dyn Input>,
}

impl <'a>MainState {
    fn new(ctx: &'a Context) -> GameResult<MainState> {

        let kbd_input = KeyboardInput::new(ctx, KeyCode::Left, KeyCode::Right);
        let kbd_input = Box::new(kbd_input);

        let s = MainState { 
            last_update: Instant::now(),
            players: vec![
                Player::new(kbd_input)
            ]
        };
        Ok(s)
    }

}

pub fn main() -> GameResult {
    let cb = ggez::ContextBuilder::new("My game", "ggez");
    let (ctx, event_loop) = &mut cb.build()?;
    let state = &mut MainState::new(&ctx)?;
    event::run(ctx, event_loop, state)
}
```

and the compiler error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:75:25
   |
75 |         let kbd_input = KeyboardInput::new(ctx, KeyCode::Left, KeyCode::Right);
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 72:7...
  --> src\main.rs:72:7
   |
72 | impl <'a>MainState {
   |       ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:75:44
   |
75 |         let kbd_input = KeyboardInput::new(ctx, KeyCode::Left, KeyCode::Right);
   |                                            ^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected std::boxed::Box<(dyn input_manager::Input + 'static)>
              found std::boxed::Box<dyn input_manager::Input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error almost always means that you are trying to store a value in a way where it can exist longer than it's lifetime.

Let's look at a specific piece of code, annotated with explicit types and lifetimes:

```rust
impl<'a> MainState {
    fn new(ctx: &'a Context) -> GameResult<MainState> {
        let kbd_input: KeyboardInput<'a> = KeyboardInput::new(ctx, KeyCode::Left, KeyCode::Right);
        let kbd_input: Box<dyn Input + 'a> = Box::new(kbd_input);

        let s: MainState = MainState {
            last_update: Instant::now(),
            players: vec![
                Player::new(kbd_input as Box<dyn Input + 'static>)
            ]
        };
        Ok(s)
    }
}
```

On line 9, you're trying to assign `kbd_input` to `Box<dyn Input>`. But `Box<dyn Input>` has no explicit lifetime, it is implicitly equivalent to `Box<dyn Input + 'static>`. So you're trying to assign a value with lifetime `'a` to a type with a static lifetime, which is not allowed.

The solution is to explicitly set the lifetime of the trait object type: `Box<dyn Input + 'a>`. This cascades and means that you'll need to add a lifetime to the `MainState` struct as well, as it now will contain a type with a non-static lifetime:

```rust
struct MainState<'a> {
  /* ... */
  players: Vec<Box<dyn Input + 'a>>,
}
```